# Add 2 jquery libraries to magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs-config.js

Im trying to load **more than 1 jquery** library into the **Magento theme**, but the 2nd trigger for flickity seems to error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flickity is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (requirejs-config.js:721)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>       at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
>       at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
>       at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
>       at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
>       at requirejs-config.js:719
>       at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>       at Module.check (require.js:866)

Code i'm using in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {

deps: [
    "jquery",
    "js/foundation",
    "js/what-input",
    "js/flickity"
],

paths: {
    'foundation'    :   'js/foundation',
    'what-input'    :   'js/what-input',
    'flickity'      :   'js/flickity'
},

shim: {
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: ['jQuery.fn.slick'],
    }
}

};
```

```
require(['jquery', 'foundation', 'what-input', 'flickity'],function($){

$(function() { // document.ready shorthand
    $(document).foundation();
    $('.main-carousel').flickity();
});

});
```

Comment: What is the jQuery which you used? Can you give us the link reference?

Comment: We are using the default version of jquery that comes with Magento 2

Comment: My fault !!! I meant what is the custom jQuery extension you used? Can you give us a link reference?

Comment: Hi, no worries, im trying to add flickity https://flickity.metafizzy.co/